# Show and hide div elements based on dropdown selection in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a question using javascript to show hide a div when using a dropdown. Code works for links and buttons but im asking if there's any way to rewrite it so it can use the SELECT option. Like if i select 'Show' from dropdown it will show me the div containing 'Hello world!'

My current Javascript:

```
<script>
function showMe(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == "block") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

And the index.html contains:

```
<select>
    <option>Hide</option>
    <option onselect="showMe('idShowMe')">Show</option>
</select>

<div id="idShowMe" style="display: none">
    <b>Hello world!</b>
</div>
```

Comment: `onselect` is not implemented on `option` elements, you need to attach `onchange` to `select` element.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your code

```js
function showMe(e) {
    var strdisplay = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var e = document.getElementById("idShowMe");
    if(strdisplay == "Hide") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showMe(this);">
    <option>Hide</option>
    <option>Show</option>
</select>

<div id="idShowMe" style="display: none">
    <b>Hello world!</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Extra question - can i also modify the code in any way so i can use diff selections to show/hide diff divs? Like 1 selecting makes 1 div visible and choosing another one blocks the first one and makes the other visible?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <select onchange="showMe(this)">
    <option>Hide</option>
    <option >Show</option>
</select>

<div id="idShowMe" style="display: none">
    <b>Hello world!</b>
</div>



function showMe(selectedOption) {

    if(selectedOption.value=="Hide") {
        document.getElementById('idShowMe').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('idShowMe').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with onchange event and then checking the selected option.
http://jsfiddle.net/hanno_drefke/dwfr224q/

the **Javascript** code:

```
var current;
function showMe(element) {
  if(current!==undefined){
    document.getElementById(current).setAttribute('style','display:none');
  }
  var fetchMe = element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-show');
  if(fetchMe!==null){
    document.getElementById(fetchMe).setAttribute('style','display:block'); 
    current=fetchMe;
  }
}
```

and minimal change ot your **HTML** Code:

```
<select onchange="showMe(this)">
    <option>Hide</option>
    <option data-show="idShowMe">Show</option>
</select>

<div id="idShowMe" style="display: none">
    <b>Hello world!</b>
</div>
```

With this solution are free to connect any layer with the corresponding id to the option. Just insert the data-show value and create a div with the id:
http://jsfiddle.net/hanno_drefke/dwfr224q/1/

Answer (score 1):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7oLr7dg/) for the same

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="showMe('idShowMe')">
    <option>Hide</option>
    <option>Show</option>
</select>

<div id="idShowMe" style="display: none">
    <b>Hello world!</b>
</div>

<script>
function showMe(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == "block") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```