# Javascript change class according radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to change some pricing tables according the option provided by the user.

For example, if he chooses 36 Months and Monthly, it will show a div (display: block;) and for the other options, 6 in total.

I was trying to follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16015970/2335912) but it will not work.. Any advise please? My goal it's to make a function that onChange/onClick it will show the divs, only after the 2 options selected.

```
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Laufzeit:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="24-m" id="laufzeit_0" checked>
        24 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="36-m" id="laufzeit_1">
        36 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="48-m" id="laufzeit_2">
        48 Months</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Abrechnung:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" value="monthly" id="abrechnung_0" checked>
        Monthly</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" value="yearly" id="abrechnung_1">
        Yearly</label>
        </td>
      <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<div class="filter-24-m">24 m</div>
<div class="filter-24-y">24 y</div>
<div class="filter-36-m">36 m</div>
<div class="filter-36-y">36 y</div>
<div class="filter-48-m">48 m</div>
<div class="filter-48-y">48 y</div>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you put your script as well?

Comment: @jiff I don't have it because I don't know how to start.. Noob here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one function. The divs are shown only after the 2 options selected.
Try something like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('input[name=abrechnung]').change(function() {
    var laufzeit = $('input[name=laufzeit]:checked').val();
    if(laufzeit.length > 0) {
      var abrechnung = $('input[name=abrechnung]:checked').val();
      $('.content').hide();
      $('.' + laufzeit + '-' + abrechnung).show();
    }
  });

  $('input[name=laufzeit]').change(function() {
    $('input[name=abrechnung]').prop('checked', false);
    $('.content').hide();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Laufzeit:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="24-m" id="laufzeit_0" checked>
        24 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="36-m" id="laufzeit_1">
        36 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" value="48-m" id="laufzeit_2">
        48 Months</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Abrechnung:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" value="monthly" id="abrechnung_0" checked>
        Monthly</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" value="yearly" id="abrechnung_1">
        Yearly</label>
        </td>
      <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="content 24-m-monthly" style="display:block">24-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 36-m-monthly">36-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 48-m-monthly">48-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 24-m-yearly">24-m yearly</div>
<div class="content 36-m-yearly">36-m yearly</div>
<div class="content 48-m-yearly">48-m yearly</div>
```

Comment: I think you can easily adapt this code with your class and input name.

Comment: I've adapted and it works but I have an issue, imagine that on the 2nd time you have already selected the monthly option, it will still not show until you press again. Is there any way to uncheck the 2nd option if you change the 1st? THANK YOU

Comment: Sorry, one more question, can I make the `24-m-monthly` checked and shown by default?

Comment: No worries. Add a `checked` attribute to your default radio inputs and a style attribute `display : block` to the relative content div. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's possible to choose the "Monthly" option by default after you choose the 24/36 or 48 Months? Sorry to re-ask this, it's important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103260/discussion-between-smdsgn-and-filipeos).

Answer (score 2):

You can have similar code for other radiobuttons also

```
$("#laufzeit_0").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        if($("#abrechnung_0").is(":checked")){
            $("div.YOUR_DIV_CLASS").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can only use "class" to identify the divs, that's why I said to change the display to block. But according your code, if I made 6 of this, in the end all divs will show. Can you adapt please?

Comment: You can change it accordingly because you didnt provided which divs you want to show

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to hide (display: none) all divs at once after I choose another option? To avoid all to be shown?
I have 6 different divs ( 1 for each possible variation )

Comment: Yes, you can use `$("div").hide();`

Comment: Select as answer if it helped you

Comment: can you add please a solution in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it by giving the radio's classes and check for any change in the class like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="laufzeit" class="laufzeit" value="24-m" id="laufzeit_0">
        24 Months</label>
```

Then you can check for any changes to show and hide the respective divs.

```
 var laufzeit;
var abrechnung;
$(".laufzeit").change(function(){
    laufzeit = $(this).attr('value');
    if(abrechnung == ""){return}
    else{
       $('.show').hide();
       $('.'+abrechnung + '-' + laufzeit).show();
       $('.'+abrechnung + '-' + laufzeit).addClass('show');
    }

});
$(".abrechnung").change(function(){
    abrechnung = $(this).attr('value');
    if(laufzeit == ""){return}
    else{
       $('.show').hide();
       $('.'+abrechnung + '-' + laufzeit).show();
       $('.'+abrechnung + '-' + laufzeit).addClass('show');
    }

});
```

With the rest looking like so:

```
    <table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Laufzeit:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" class="laufzeit" value="24-m" id="laufzeit_0">
            24 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" class="laufzeit" value="36-m" id="laufzeit_1">
        36 Months</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="laufzeit" class="laufzeit" value="48-m" id="laufzeit_2">
        48 Months</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>Abrechnung:</td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" class="abrechnung" value="monthly" id="abrechnung_0">
        Monthly</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="abrechnung" class="abrechnung" value="yearly" id="abrechnung_1">
        Yearly</label>
        </td>
      <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
<div class="content 24-m-monthly show">24-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 36-m-monthly">36-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 48-m-monthly">48-m monthly</div>
<div class="content 24-m-yearly">24-m yearly</div>
<div class="content 36-m-yearly">36-m yearly</div>
<div class="content 48-m-yearly">48-m yearly</div>
```

Comment: I'll take a look now for you @FilipeOS

Comment: This should now function as intended if you can add the classes to the inputs? @FilipeOS