# Javascript show hidden div when select option is selected error

Tags: javascript, css, select, hide, show

I'm trying to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16015970/3105310) for a little bit more complex select list, but doesn't seem to work.

If value=0 is selected, it should show a hidden div.
If value=1 is selected, it should show another hidden div.

I'm new to JS. Can you please help to find the error?

HTML:

```html
<select name="status" id="soflow2" onchange="showDiv(this)">
<option>Select</option>  
<option value="0">Single</option>
<option value="1">Married</option>
<option value="1">Registered Legal Partnership</option>
<option value="1">Remarried</option>
<option value="0">Legally Separated</option>
<option value="0">Divorced</option>
<option value="0">Widowed</option>
<option value="1">Informal Partnership</option>
</select>

<div id="stepsHIDDEN">
<button type="button" class="nextstep"><a href="04Step.html">Next</a></button>
</div>

<div id="questionHIDDEN">
<p>
Is your spouse gainfully employed?
</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```html
function showDiv(elem){
if(elem.value == 1)
document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
} else { document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, an `<option>` that doesn't explicitly have a value will attempt to use it's text, so when you do not have a selection, the `value` property will be "Select".

You can use that to show or hide or `<div>` accordingly :

```
<!-- You may want to initially hide your section since it won't have a value -->
<div id="stepsHIDDEN" style='display:none;'>
    <button type="button" class="nextstep">
        <a href="04Step.html">Next</a>
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function showDiv(elem){
        // If your value is `Select`, then hide your element
        if(elem.value == 'Select'){
            document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = "none";
        } 
        else{ 
            document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

or if you would prefer using a one liner function :

```
function showDiv(elem){
   document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = (elem.value == 'Select') ? "none" : "block";      
}
```

**Complete Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="status" id="soflow2" onchange="showDiv(this)">
    <option>Select</option>  
    <option value="0">Single</option>
    <option value="1">Married</option>
    <option value="1">Registered Legal Partnership</option>
    <option value="1">Remarried</option>
    <option value="0">Legally Separated</option>
    <option value="0">Divorced</option>
    <option value="0">Widowed</option>
    <option value="1">Informal Partnership</option>
  </select>

  <div id="stepsHIDDEN" style='display:none;'>
    <button type="button" class="nextstep">
        <a href="04Step.html">Next</a>
    </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function showDiv(elem){
      if(elem.value == 'Select'){
        document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = "none";
      } 
      else{ 
        document.getElementById('stepsHIDDEN').style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried and it worked for one div, but I have 2, and depending on the selected option's value (0 or 1) I have to show 2 different divs, not just one. In that case how would the code look like?

Comment: There are a few ways you could handle that. Implementing a `switch` statement or just using the second inline-if approach I mentioned earlier. You can see [examples of these here](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/d5dfdcf09396afe4ef01551405bf513f).