# Sending hidden value of html5 datalist to database

Tags: php, database, html, html-datalist

I'm relatively new to html5 and I'm trying to put together a webpage using a datalist object.  I populate my datalists from a database, an example is shown below:

What I want to achieve is for the user to see the list of dates in the dropdown box and when they click a button to post the associated data-value number to a database (this is a primary key).  The question is how do I get hold of the data-value to use in php to send to a database (I can get hold of the value in javascript but I don't want to use javascript to connect to the database as I'm told this is not good practice).  Thanks very much in advance.  Martyn

```
<input type="text" list="eventList" autocomplete="off" id="searchEvents" name="searchEvents">
<datalist id="eventList">
    <option data-value="1" value="2016-06-02">2016-06-02</option>
    <option data-value="2" value="2016-06-09">2016-06-09</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't get your *Primary Key* from user submitted data. Better to calculate or auto generate that on the server-side based on the user-provided data.

Anyway, you can add hidden fields in your form using something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenvar" value="some secret" />
```

You would put this in an [HTML Form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). You can have JavaScript *insert* that element into the form when the user selects an option from the dropdown.

The form's submitted data goes to the script/url provided in the `action` attribute of the form. On the server side, PHP gets the data in the var [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Edit based on OP's comment:

You will *still* need to add the hidden element as above but you can do it with an element like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="searchEventsID" value="" />
```

Leave it empty first and then have JS set the value to the corresponding `data-value` attribute.

Note that both examples are for a *`hidden`* element so the user won't see it. But it will be submitted to the server when the user submits it.

Edit 2:

Set the [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute of the select `<input>` tag to a JS function which will do the necessary. See the links above on how to do that. And maybe google for some tutorials. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16015970/1431750) has a similar "structure" but you'll need to figure out what you need to do. Specifically,

```
var hidden_val = document.getElementById('eventList').getAttribute('data-value');
document.getElementById('searchEventsID').value = hidden_val;
// done in two lines for clarity but you can do it in one.
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear.  The value held in "data-value" is the key associated with, in this case, the date of an event which is obtained from a query to a table in the database (there are other datalists cotaining names with their associated keys obtained from other tables).  Once the user has selected the date of the event from one data list and the name from another data list I wish to write the corresponding keys to another table in the database that links events and names with a corresponding score.  I'd like the user to see names and dates in the drop down boxes but to send keys.

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more detail about using hidden fields please, I'm not quite sure how to pass the selected value to the hidden field. Thanks for your help, Martyn

Comment: I've added _even more_ info now. You have a basic idea of what to do. Try implementing something and then ask another question specific to an issue you face. Btw, there are links in my answer to W3Schools' tutorials. Read through them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a go later.