# Pure JS List in Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have a simple list that I put into an array.  What I'd like to do is once a specific item in that list/array has been chosen: show content-X.

How do I structure the If statement to check for a specific selection within the array to then force a particular action?

```
<select name="list" id="list">
<option name="one" id="one">One</option>    
<option name="two" id="two">two</option>
<option name="three" id="three">three</option>
</select>

var ListArr = [];
var list = document.getElementById("list");

for(i=0; i<list.options.length; i++)
{
ListArr[i]=list.options[i].value;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript show hidden div when select option is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select name="list" id="list">
<option name="one" id="one">One</option>    
<option name="two" id="two">two</option>
<option name="three" id="three">three</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
(function(){
var ListArr = [];
var list = document.getElementById("list");

for(i=0; i<list.options.length; i++)
{
ListArr[i]=list.options[i].value;
}

list.addEventListener("change", function(){
 var x = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;
 console.log("specific item in that list/array has been chosen: show content- "+ListArr[x]);
 alert("specific item in that list/array has been chosen: show content- "+ListArr[x]);
});
}());
```

[Working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/NIHAR_SARKAR/27r5z8ru/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (just replace the alert with your own functionality):

```js
function changeOption() {
  var selected = document.getElementById("list").value;
  alert(selected);
}
```

```html
<select name="list" id="list" onchange="changeOption()">
  <option name="one" id="one">One</option>
  <option name="two" id="two">two</option>
  <option name="three" id="three">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way your Select menu is setup, you can easily show an element based on the value of the option like so:

HTML

```
<select name="list" id="list">
  <option name="one" value="one">One</option>    
  <option name="two" value="two">two</option>
  <option name="three" value="three">three</option>
</select>

<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("list").onchange=function(){
  var hiddenID = this.value;
  document.getElementById(hiddenID).style.display = "block";
};
```

You basically need to give an `ID` to an element that matches the `value` of the option in the select list.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q30gcfg4/