# Display style's when password is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my wordpress site i have a page that can only be accessed by a password, this is using the wordpress built in password protected visibility.

What i want is when the user inputs the password, i want to add css that will display another item in the header menu that is currently hidden.

```
#menu-item-222 {
display:none;
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using php?

**EDIT:**

Looking back i wasn't really clear in my answer, What i wanted to do was show the styles after the user has inputted the correct password and then show the hidden box on page/change and refresh

This is what i got so far from the answers.

```
jQuery("input[name=Submit]").click(function() {
if(jQuery("input[type='password']").val() == 'test12345'){
jQuery("#menu-item-222").css("display","block")
}
});
```

Comment: Not using PHP, using JavaScript yes. PHP is Server-Side, JavaScript is Client-Side

Comment: You can achieve this using Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript show hidden div when select option is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected)

Comment: Please do understand that php is a server side language and javascript is a client side language. You can makes changes on client side using client side languages only.

Comment: @Sagar not true at all - you can create the entire site in just php...

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you can create entire site using just php. But after the page has been generated and pushed to the client side, php cannot take action can it?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i thinkl the key phrase is make **changes**.

Comment: Unless of course you want to hide something on refresh, which can then be done with a simple if statement. But the way this question reads is that the user types into the box, a header menu should appear, thus the requirement for adding a class or similar is required via JS

Comment: @Sagar you have to create concurrent connections - can be done, but easier to do with both php and js (in the form of ajax)

Comment: Just a comment for those answering the question: if you're checking that the entered password matches a given string on the client side that site has no security: the password must be checked/verified server side.

Comment: `when the user inputs the password` is unclear. **before** or **after** login ? 1) you can use JS to show/hide something using some `on key event` but that won't be related to secure/verified password, just hitting the input 2) verify pwd server-side, and if OK, use statement to show (or not) the 'hidden part'. 1st option: jQuery / no reload needed - 2nd option: PHP / refresh. But it's not that clear what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Please check this. You need to enter right password to display hidden element on top.

```js
$("#pwd").keyup(function() {
        if ($('#pwd').val() == "test123"){
            $('#content').show('slow');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
    Testing Content
</div>
<form>
    Enter the password to see the content:
    <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just know that the "hidden" content isn't really hidden, since you can just see it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using javascript or jquery by possibly checking the value of your input.Let's assume that your password is '12345'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("input[type='password']").val() == '12345'){
    $("#menu-item-222").css("display","block")
  }
})
```