# On select one option don't send text box value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in my website, in that i have added select dropdown. I select option,   if we click on last option, one text box will open. If we select other options, this text box will be hidden.
While sending mail, if user clicks on other option(except last option) mail is sending, but it is also taking that custom text box value. This value should send only if I click on last option. Otherwise it should hide. How to do this, please help me.
Here is my code

```
<form action="inc/contact.php" method="POST" class="theme-form-one form-validation" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" name="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *" name="phone">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email *" name="email">

    <select id="contact-services" name="services" onchange='CheckServices(this.value);'>

      <option value=""> Services Interested</option>
      <option value="3D Modeling">3D Modeling</option>
      <option value="3D Rendering">3D Rendering</option>
      <option value="3D Animation">3D Animation</option>
      <option value="Custom">Custom Requirement</option>

    </select>

  <input type="text" name="service" id="service" style='display:none;'/>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
  <button class="theme-button-four btn3">SEND MESSAGE</button>

</form>
```

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckServices(val){

  var element=document.getElementById('service');

  if(val=='Services Interested'||val=='Custom')
  element.style.display='block';
  else  
    element.style.display='none';
  }

</script>
```

Here is my php code for sending mail

```
<?php

$to = "abc@mail.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "subject";

$fields = array();
$fields{"name"}    = "Name";
$fields{"email"}    = "Email";
$fields{"phone"}    = "Phone";
$fields{"services"} = "Services";
$fields{"service"}    = "Service";
$fields{"message"}   = "Message";

$body = "Message:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript show hidden div when select option is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected)

Comment: Here I am asking how to send mail with and without custom text box value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields = array();
$fields{"name"}    = "Name";
$fields{"email"}    = "Email";
$fields{"phone"}    = "Phone";
$fields{"services"} = "Services";
if(isset($_POST["service"]) && !empty($_POST["service"])) $fields{"service"}    = "Service";
$fields{"message"}   = "Message";
```

This may help you. The problem with your code is you are pushing array even if you `service` is empty. so that's why it is included in your mail body. so, you just have to put an `if` condition to ensure that the value of `service` is not empty

Comment: thank you so much @Zainul Abideen.  This solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check if the `services` textbox has a certain value contained it in.  If it does then we can include it or not include it.  I also cleaned up your code a bit.

Try this:

```
$to = "abc@mail.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "subject";

if(isset($_POST['services']) && $_POST['services'] != 'Custom'){

unset($_POST['service']);

}

$body = "Message:\n\n";

foreach($_POST as $a => $b){
$body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n", ucfirst($a), $_POST[$a]);
 }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function CheckServices(val){
      var element=document.getElementById('service');
      if(val=='Services Interested'||val=='Custom')
          element.style.display='block';
      else  
       element.style.display='none';
       element.value = ''; // reset element value
     }
</script>

  Check element on php code
  if(!empty($_POST['service']) {
     // post data in mmail
  }
```