# Set a variable through a drop down list in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

```
def scan(request):
    scan = Stock.objects.all()
    hammer = Stock.objects.filter(Hammer=100)
    belthold = Stock.objects.filter(Belthold=100)

    context = {'All':scan, 'Belthold':belthold, 'Hammer':hammer

    }

    return render(request, 'scanner/scan.html', context)
```

This is my views.py file. I want to add a dropdown list to my html page containing the context dictionary which changes the query filters according.

This is my current html page:

```
{% for i in Hammer %}

       <tr>
           <td>{{i.script}}</td>
           <td>{{i.open}}</td>
           <td>{{i.high}}</td>
           <td>{{i.low}}</td>
           <td>{{i.close}}</td>
           <td>{{i.Volume}}</td>
           <td>{{i.Change}}</td>
       </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

The 'Hammer' need to be replaced by whatever selection is made from the dropdown list.

THANKS!!

Comment: you'll have to use javascript to set section visibility or ajax to get data on drop down event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically change Hammer in a template for loop. You can use the approach below or change the approach as to how you want everything displayed.

You have to use Javascript for that. You first need to give id's to all the  tags you have in the for loop.

```
<td id="{{i.script}}_myid"> ...
```

Then with Javascript access the change in the dropdown menu's value and then update the respective td's accordingly:

```
document.getElementbyId('dropdown').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
// Change td's here: document.getElementbyId(..._myid).innerHTML = "" })
```

To pass Hammer in your JS you can either do an inline script (which many dont recommend) or a separate JS file added as a script tag below. You can use serializers to pass on the objects from Python to JS.

Comment: I am a complete noob at coding, can u pl make it more elaborate...THANKSS! if u can write the code plss, i hv been trying this for days

Comment: I am no expert myself. But essentially you have learn about 3 things for your question to be answered and considering you are closest to your application you will be able to figure it out. First Django serializers: can be found on their documentation website; next basic javascript and element tracking: many videos on Youtube and third updating: can be done with the second suggestion; again many videos.

Comment: Alright, i will do that. But a few clarifications pls: 1) by defining id's, u meaning allocating each of tds a unique number like 1,2,3 or id1, id2 etc.   2) "Change td's here"; that's where I put the whole td code with changed ids? And what abt the "getElementbyId(..._myid)" and the inner html? Little help will be dearly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: 1. yes, you will be giving the tds a unique id. 2. Then using that unique id to "find" them in the document (current page) and then changing the content within it. The finding is 'getElementbyId' and the innerHTML is just that.. the inner html in the td tags.