# Displaying certain categories based on certain input

Tags: html

This code for a form that I can input information to create something. My problem is that I this form to show certain sections based on user input but I don't know how to do that. For example, for the Type of Location section if I click Original I want the Information section to appear only and if I click Crossover/Realistic then I want the Link section to appear only. Can someone help with that?
HTML Code:

```
<form method="post">             
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Type of Location</label>
                <select name="locationtype" class="form-control" required>
                    <option>Select one</option>
                    <option>Original</option>
                    <option>Crossover/Realistic</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Picture ID</label>
                     <select name="pictureid" class="form-control" required>
                                <option>Select one</option>
                                {% for x in pictures %}
                                    <option value="{{x.pictureid}}">{{x.picturename}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Information</label>
                         <textarea name="information" class="form-control" style="color: black">{{ location.information }}</textarea>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label> Link</label>
                <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" value="{{ location.link }}" required>
              </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show a hidden div when a select option is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/how-can-i-show-a-hidden-div-when-a-select-option-is-selected)

Comment: What does these `{% for x in pictures %}` stand for? Which language is this?
You would need another language like javascript e.g to get user input and show it on the page.

Comment: Please post valid code either way - looking for a typo can be a mess. *"I don't know how to do this, please code this for me"* is not really what we do here. What have you tried? See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please only post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#locationtype").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "original") {
        $(".dynamic-block").hide();
        $("#informationBlock").show();
    }
    else if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "crossover/realistic") {
        $(".dynamic-block").hide();
        $("#linkBlock").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type of Location</label>
        <select id="locationtype" name="locationtype" class="form-control" required>
            <option>Select one</option>
            <option>Original</option>
            <option>Crossover/Realistic</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Picture ID</label>
        <select name="pictureid" class="form-control" required>
            <option>Select one</option>
            {% for x in pictures %}
            <option value="{{x.pictureid}}">{{x.picturename}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group dynamic-block" id="informationBlock" style="display: none;">
        <label>Information</label>
        <textarea name="information" class="form-control" style="color: black">{{ location.information }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group dynamic-block" id="linkBlock" style="display: none;">
        <label> Link</label>
        <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" value="{{ location.link }}" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok now the info inputted in these categories are part of a table; this will update info put in a table so how do I modify it to where this behavior applies for infinite numbers of entries in a table?

Comment: I think you are not clear with your questions.

Comment: This form updates individual entries in a table with the information listed above. My question is how do I modify it to where it goes for multiple entries in the table? I am asking about the javascript portion.